# Javascript array object return empty array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I try to filter jsonplaceholder comments to get by id but return empty array

```
axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments').then((result) => {

 // const arr = _.find(result.data, { postID: 1});
 // console.log(arr);
 console.log(result.data.filter(x => x.postID === 1))

}).catch((err) => {
 console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: Typo. `postId` not `postID`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `postID` by `postId`:

`console.log(result.data.filter(x => x.postId === 1))`

Answer (score 0):

Log both the result data and the post id property type. So it could either be an absence  of data from the response in the request or it could be a flawed comparison because of the "===" operandi

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing `postID` instead of `postId`.

Working example at [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-scott-zf7bx?file=/src/index.js:28-303)

```js
axios
  .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments")
  .then((result) => {
    // const arr = _.find(result.data, { postID: 1});
    // console.log(arr);
    console.log(result.data.filter((x) => x.postId === 1));
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```